# How to return a list from java to JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing string from Java into JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247002/passing-string-from-java-into-jni)
>   [passing string array from java to C with JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972207/passing-string-array-from-java-to-c-with-jni)

I need to return a list **List < String >** from java to jni. How should i do this and i also need to convert the returned value as an **array of std::string** at JNI end. Can anyone please tell me how to go about this.

Comment: Not a duplicate: the op asks about returning a `List<string>` from Java and into the C++ world (JNI). The "possible duplicate" questions are about returning `Object[]`, which is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exchange of data bettween Java and C can by peformed using only primitive types. So by JNI is not possible. An alternative could be [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) or [JavaCpp](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/).

Comment: is there a way i can convert a String[] sent from java to string[] at jni end

Comment: No. But you can do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972207/passing-string-array-from-java-to-c-with-jni

Comment: even when i do that i am not bein able to specify the return type of my jni function as **const char*[]**

Comment: Dam man. you are to lazy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047166/return-a-string-array-on-a-jni-method

Comment: what i did was to convert List<String> to String[] and sent to jni class and there i converted the jobjectArray to vector<string> and passed it to my cpp class