# Pass Data from Java File to cpp

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse

I am trying to create object detection algorithm in java from the sample code 
[here](http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/opencv_nonfree_android_jni_demo) .
However in the code the image value is hardcoded.Is there way i can pass the image location on my own.

```
   const char * imgInFile = "/sdcard/nonfree/img1.jpg";// Need to pass custom values
const char * imgOutFile = "/sdcard/nonfree/img1_result.jpg";
```

Thank You

Comment: would be replaced with `String` or `byte[]` or `char[]` and note that each `char` in java takes 2 bytes :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in Java use

```
private String imgInFile;
private String imgOutFile;
```

Then either read these values from an input file, or get them from arguments passed to you application when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a string parameter to `runDemo` method. You should change method signature in java and fix jni method prototype in nonfree_jni.cpp file and... [Goolge how to pass string to jni.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247002/passing-string-from-java-into-jni)