# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL - My code or not?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

Currently developing an Android app which included a small native code part in C, I have a JNI error that I dont know if it is related to my code or not.

I read the logcat, but I am definitely not sure the problem is due to my code. What in the logcat says it ?

Here is what I believe is the relevant logcat part :

```
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to GetIntArrayElements
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Runnable
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x15600000 self=0x9b615600
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | sysTid=4571 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9b8c5970
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | state=R schedstat=( 266149744 1857862073 357 ) utm=9 stm=17 core=1 HZ=100
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | stack=0x9b7c7000-0x9b7c9000 stackSize=1022KB
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #00 pc 0047ead1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+209)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #01 pc 0057c183  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+355)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #02 pc 00577683  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+83)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #03 pc 00395246  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1254)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #04 pc 003956b1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, char*)+113)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #05 pc 0014f207  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+71)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #06 pc 0014e42d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckArray(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jarray*)+285)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #07 pc 0014dc4a  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::JniValueType)+170)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #08 pc 0014cf85  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*)+853)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #09 pc 00158f9e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetPrimitiveArrayElements(char const*, art::Primitive::Type, _JNIEnv*, _jarray*, unsigned char*)+942)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #10 pc 0014522f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetIntArrayElements(_JNIEnv*, _jintArray*, unsigned char*)+47)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #11 pc 0001a98a  /system/lib/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::JvmtiAllocationListener::ObjectAllocated(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>*, unsigned int)+538)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #12 pc 0012ed69  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap24AllocObjectWithAllocatorILb1ELb1ENS_6mirror16SetLengthVisitorEEEPNS3_6ObjectEPNS_6ThreadENS_6ObjPtrINS3_5ClassEEEjNS0_13AllocatorTypeERKT1_+1961)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #13 pc 001895f1  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::mirror::ObjectArray<art::mirror::Object>::Alloc(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Class>, int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+129)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #14 pc 00186583  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+2147)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #15 pc 000e1d83  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool)+163)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #16 pc 000e1cd7  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (jit_compile_method+55)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #17 pc 003b8b3f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool)+303)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #18 pc 003bb982  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+626)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #19 pc 0059855b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+91)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #20 pc 00597fab  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+139)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #21 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #22 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #23 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]   (no managed stack frames)
05-14 19:27:27.869 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] 
05-14 19:27:29.080 4565-4565/com.example.jni I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-14 19:27:29.454 4565-4577/com.example.jni I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2089(292KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 9MB/15MB, paused 14.102ms total 2.626s
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] Runtime aborting...
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] All threads:
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] DALVIK THREADS (31):
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x15600000 self=0x9b615600
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=4571 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9b8c5970
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | state=R schedstat=( 300303782 2898196599 469 ) utm=12 stm=18 core=1 HZ=100
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x9b7c7000-0x9b7c9000 stackSize=1022KB
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 0047ead1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+209)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 0057c183  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+355)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 00577683  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+83)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 005974fe  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+1118)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 0058e9e6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+534)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 0058e232  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+882)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 0055f1a1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, art::Thread*) const+289)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #07 pc 0055edc0  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&) const+176)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #08 pc 0054d356  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+198)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #09 pc 0011fb23  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #10 pc 0065f26b  /system/lib/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1051)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #11 pc 003954ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1951)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #12 pc 003956b1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, char*)+113)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #13 pc 0014f207  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+71)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #14 pc 0014e42d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckArray(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jarray*)+285)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #15 pc 0014dc4a  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::JniValueType)+170)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #16 pc 0014cf85  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*)+853)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #17 pc 00158f9e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetPrimitiveArrayElements(char const*, art::Primitive::Type, _JNIEnv*, _jarray*, unsigned char*)+942)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #18 pc 0014522f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetIntArrayElements(_JNIEnv*, _jintArray*, unsigned char*)+47)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #19 pc 0001a98a  /system/lib/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::JvmtiAllocationListener::ObjectAllocated(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>*, unsigned int)+538)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #20 pc 0012ed69  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap24AllocObjectWithAllocatorILb1ELb1ENS_6mirror16SetLengthVisitorEEEPNS3_6ObjectEPNS_6ThreadENS_6ObjPtrINS3_5ClassEEEjNS0_13AllocatorTypeERKT1_+1961)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #21 pc 001895f1  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::mirror::ObjectArray<art::mirror::Object>::Alloc(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Class>, int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+129)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #22 pc 00186583  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+2147)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #23 pc 000e1d83  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool)+163)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #24 pc 000e1cd7  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (jit_compile_method+55)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #25 pc 003b8b3f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool)+303)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #26 pc 003bb982  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+626)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #27 pc 0059855b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+91)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #28 pc 00597fab  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+139)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #29 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #30 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #31 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] 
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x15600088 self=0xa3459c00
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=4572 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9b7c4970
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 1130252 9782646 31 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x9b6ca000-0x9b6cc000 stackSize=1006KB
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0xd7/0x19f
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0x6e/0x9c
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: syscall_after_call+0x0/0x4
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 00000ac4  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 00074391  /system/lib/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+33)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 0002abf7  /system/lib/libc.so (sigwait+119)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 00568549  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalSet::Wait()+57)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 00567fda  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+250)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 005663bf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+319)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #07 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #08 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] 
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x15600110 self=0x9b613200
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=4573 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x88e90970
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 18920369 50020694 64 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x88d96000-0x88d98000 stackSize=1006KB
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: poll_schedule_timeout+0x2e/0x4b
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_select+0x584/0x5c3
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: core_sys_select+0x191/0x2b0
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_pselect6+0xec/0x16e
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: syscall_after_call+0x0/0x4
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 00000ac4  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 0007419b  /system/lib/libc.so (__pselect6+43)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 000287c8  /system/lib/libc.so (select+136)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 0064ad44  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpAdbState::ProcessIncoming()+372)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 003ad55c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpState::Run()+1948)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 003ac553  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::StartJdwpThread(void*)+51)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #07 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #08 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-14 19:27:29.605 4565-4571/com.example.jni A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
...
```

Comment: GetIntArrayElements is returning null. kindly check your C code and handle null scenario

Comment: I never use GetIntArrayElements, but I do use function of the openssl/sha.h library like ```SHA256```. Is there a way to know when does the null scenario happen ?

Comment: what method are you hitting in JNI? is that taking in some parameters?

Comment: Yes it does, it takes a couple of jstring as entries, and return a jstring.

Comment: maybe this link will help? http://leo.ugr.es/elvira/devel/Tutorial/Java/native1.1/implementing/array.html

Comment: Okay I understand the point. But I convert all my jstring entries into const char * using ```env->GetStringUTFChars()``` before working in them. Is that not enough ?

Comment: how about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247103/6142219

Comment: as per the link, I think its (*env)->GetStringUTFChars()

Comment: I am not sure this is the problem here. (*env) instead of env does not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the initial question :

- yes the problem was due to my C++ code
- I did not find a way to read that from the logcat

I simply confirmed that it was due to my code by quickly coding the function in Java, and it was never crashing with this one.

As you may have stubble upon this : https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack, the logcat and ndk-stack should theoretically give information about where the crash happen. Unfortunately I was not able to use ndk-stack properly. It simply output nothing. Maybe because I feed it with the wrong symbolic file. I have absolutely no idea. It simply outputs:

`********** Crash dump: **********`.

As side note that may be useful if like me the environment variables are not properly set, the ndk-stack tool is as : 
    /Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-stack

And symbolic files are at ( I don't know which one to use, tried them all) :

```
/Users/homefolder/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86
/Users/homefolder/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a
/Users/homefolder/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a
/Users/homefolder/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/debug/0/lib/x86
/Users/homefolder/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a
/Users/homefolder/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/x86
```

Because I was not able to use ndk-stack I rewrite the function in Java and all crashes were gone.
For information, I tried to ass try/catch in the C++ code and around the JNI calls, but this was not stopping crashes to occurs.